I would like to know how the gx command gets the file path on the file manager
I am trying to implement getting the full path of the file on the cursor in the buffer of any file manager plugin. This is easy if you use a specific file manager API.
As an example, in Netrw it would look like:
local path = netrw_call('NetrwFile', vim.fn['netrw#Call']('NetrwGetWord'))

And in Oil.nvim, it would look like:
local oil = require('oil')
local path = oil.get_current_dir() .. oil.get_cursor_entry().name

While working on this implementation, I noticed that if you hover over a file displayed by Netrw or Oil.nvim and type the gx command, you can open that file with the system's default handler, independent of the location of the current directory.
So I was curious if there might be a way to obtain the full path of a file without relying on a specific API as described above.
After much research, I found the command vim.fn.expand("%:p:h"), but this did not work. As a test, I used Oil.nvim to open a specific directory on Windows (say C:\Windows) and ran this command and got the following result:
oil:///C/Windows

This differs from the result of executing a similar command on a regular buffer:
C:\Windows

I think I can implement it by handling exceptions, but I'm wondering if there might be a more efficient method.
If anyone knows of a better method, I would be very grateful to hear it.

There's no such thing as "common API for Vim file managers". The best scenario is when it's done as simple as "whole file path in every line of a buffer". Then it becomes trivial to get path under cursor. Otherwise, you need to rewrite your code every time. And, by the way, I just can't see how it may be useful to support all those different plugins at once. After all, they all do similar things. So just choose one you like most or write a new one by yourself if none fits you. It's not that hard and could be easier than supporting ton of them.

The % in expand("%:p:h") represents the name of the current buffer, which…

doesn't seem to be what you are actually after,
and can reasonably be assumed to be different from plugin to plugin anyway.

Furthermore, the gx command is not a native Vim command. It has historically been provided by Netrw, which is distributed with Vim, using its own state and methods, etc. Other file explorers can implement a gx command as well but, as they are all third-party plugins (including Netrw itself), they are not required to do so and… there is no universal API or even "guideline" to help with that.
All you have at your disposal is, at a low level:

Vim's own file-related functions found at :help file-functions,
functionalities provided by embedded scripting languages like Lua, Ruby, Python, etc.

and, at a higher level:

whatever API, if any, is exposed by those plugins.

FWIW, the general pattern is to:

yank the word under the cursor,
put it into a variable,
try to get a proper filename out of it with some of the functions under :help file-functions.

Note that it may require some context that may or may not be available at the time of execution, like parent directory, filetype, etc.
Here is a very good low-level gx rewrite to serve as inspiration.
Expanding on @Matt's comment, there are dozens of file explorers out there, and they all work around the lack of an actual "common API for Vim file managers" with various mutually incompatible hacks. That lack of common API will undoubtedly force you to make a choice:

implement your generic gx-like command entirely on your own, only using low-level methods,
implement your generic gx-like command using the private APIs of some or all of the myriad file explorers, eventually implementing a low-level fallback anyway.

None of those seem particularly thrilling to me.
